# ASP.NET MVC3 User Login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, membership

I have a User model with:

```
[Required]
public string Password { get; set; }

[Required]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

I have a `MyMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider` containing:

```
public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
{
   if (username == ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultUsername"] && password == ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultUserPassword"])
   {
       return true;
   }
   else
   {
       return false;
   }
}
```

My LogOn action looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(User model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

The Problem:

When I specify the correct username and password, I can't seem to go to actions and controllers which contain the `[Authorize]` attribute. When I use breakpoint, it DOES fall in to `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");` but denies access to the Index page.

Can anyone see where I am going horribly wrong?

Comment: I would definitely **not** recommend storing *any* type of credentials in your web.config on a live site.

Comment: This is just temporary. I will have a proper implementation later on :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the auth cookie so the next action recognises that the user is authenticated.

```
....
if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, true);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
....
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I understand now why the SetAuthCookie is required :)